# Blob labelling in OpenCv2.0

Tags: c++, android, opencv, blob, tracking

I read somewhere on stackoverflow previously that cvBlobLib had been integrated into opencv2.0 but i definitely can't find it and there's no mention of it in the [documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/index.html).

I'm trying to do simple blob labelling on a static image. Writing an algorithm to do this from scratch is harder than it sounds so I was wondering if anyone had any other knowledge on this. I have seen cvBlob on Google Code but that's very much an external library.

While i'm testing on a PC, my code needs to be used on an Android phone, so using external libraries (other than OpenCV) would be a massive pain.

Thanks for reading

Comment: Simple connected component extraction can be done using the `cvFindContours()` function in OpenCV. No external libraries are required. These links should clearly illustrate the rather straightforward procedure. [Connected Components](http://www.bukisa.com/articles/263221_connected-components-using-opencv)  and  [Filtering CCs](http://www.bukisa.com/articles/267697_filtering-connected-components) By blob labeling if you mean this, then I hope you'll find it useful.